# menu asp.net renders fine offline but online have problems

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, menu

I'm new in the asp.net world and im trying to use the menu control (instead of use a CSS one).
Orientation="Horizontal" menu with some sub-menu items.
When i run the website local it seems right, but when i upload it is absolutely different:
- Chrome renders sub-menus not as vertical pop-up.
- Mozzilla and IE9 dont take the CssClass and not the HorizontalPadding and VerticalPadding.

the link to see how it work online: http://www.symbols.it/prof/default.aspx

Really thanks,

Lionel

Comment: I think other css is overriding them.

Comment: Thanks, DotNetter. The big problem is that I use RenderingMode="List" and when i inspect the elements on a "webdevelopment tool" it appears like a table. It means that it is a rendering problem. What u think?

Comment: It is possible that the hosting has an older version of .NET framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks something messy overriding your `CSS` as said above and try to check with yout `target Framework` in web.config file with your hosting provider configuration.

In projects that target the .NET Framework 4 or later versions, the compilation element of the Web.config file contains a targetFramework attribute, as shown:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>...</configSections>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" 
        targetFramework="4.0">
    ...
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank again. I am searching this CSS. Im Sorry DotNetter, but I'm new to this things. Could you tell me how can try to check with my target Framework in web.config file. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome if your problem is solved accept and close otherwise your question will be in the list of open one's.

Comment: Of course. I'm only have to know how can try to check with my target Framework in web.config file. Thnks,

Comment: Thank you. I added the line <compilation... on the web.config file but it seems that my hosting provider do not allow to make this kind of changes. Question answered! Thank you again DotNetter.

Comment: glad to hear at last that you got it rectified :)

Comment: I used to do websites in HTML/CSS. Is not simple to use and control a .net component.

Comment: It's pretty easy to work with asp.net one we get used to it :)